# How to stream client side WebRTC audio to google speech to text server

Tags: node.js, sockets, webrtc, google-speech-api

This in a nutshell is what I am attempting to do:

Browser/WebRTc audio ==> server side (node js)  socket.io server ==> google cloud

I’m using webRTC in the browser to capture audio from the browser mic. This audio is sent as an object with a base64 string to the  socket.io server as it comes in. This part works as I can see the incoming data when I log it.

Where am I stuck is sending this stream to the google cloud speech api to have it transcribed.

There is a Quickstart application in the google cloud [speech documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize) for streaming microphone data to google speech and getting real time transcription. I managed to get this to work, however it uses the computer’s microphone. The application uses node node-record-lpcm16 and SoX to access the computer’s microphone and pipe the stream to the google cloud api.

Audio is sent to google cloud via the StreamingRecognize method on the SpeechClient. The request object is passed to that method. The request object has field called audio_content, which is where I’m thinking the incoming audio stream should go(???).

Below is the server file that contains the  socket.io instance and code from the google cloud Quickstart application that worked with node-record-lpcm16 package.

```
let io = require('socket.io')(3000, {
  cors: {origin: ['http://localhost:8080']},
})

const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');
  
// Create a speech client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();


const encoding = 'LINEAR16';
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = 'en-US';

//speech client request header
const request = {
  config: {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    languageCode: languageCode,
    enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
  },
  interimResults: false, // If you want interim results, set this to true
};

  // Create a recognize stream, this makes a request and waits for response (transcription)
    const recognizeStream = client
    .streamingRecognize(request) //send request passed to streamingRecognize method
    .on('error', console.error) //throw error if error returned
    .on('data', data =>
    {
      console.log(data.results[0].alternatives[0].words)
      process.stdout.write(
          
        data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0]
          ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
          : '\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n'
      )
    }
    );



//Create socket and listen for audio stream from webRTC

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log(socket.id)

  //TODO: how to send this stream to google speech?
  socket.on('audioStream', (obj) => {
      //obj is JSON object structured like this: {"audio_data": base64 string....}
     
      //verified here that stream is being received continuously
      console.log(obj)
      
  })
 
})

console.log('socket server running')
```

This is how the audio data is sent from webRTC script:

```
 socket.emit('audioStream', 
                      { audio_data: base64data.split('base64,')[1]}
                    )
```

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you use the [Web Audio Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) instead if you are just interested in transcribing the audio from the video.

Here is how I did it with a nodejs sever and react client app. It is uploaded to [github here](https://github.com/untilhamza/Google-speech-to-text-App-in-react/tree/main)

1. You need an audio worklet script. (Put it in the public folder because by default the `Worklet.addModule()` API expects a URL of a JavaScript file with the module to add. [Refer to the docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worklet/addModule). By putting it in the public folder, it will be loaded from our web app's static files)

**recorderWorkletProcessor.js** (saved in `public/src/worklets/recorderWorkletProcessor.js`)

```
/**
  An in-place replacement for ScriptProcessorNode using AudioWorklet
*/
class RecorderProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  // 0. Determine the buffer size (this is the same as the 1st argument of ScriptProcessor)
  bufferSize = 2048;
  // 1. Track the current buffer fill level
  _bytesWritten = 0;

  // 2. Create a buffer of fixed size
  _buffer = new Float32Array(this.bufferSize);

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.initBuffer();
  }

  initBuffer() {
    this._bytesWritten = 0;
  }

  isBufferEmpty() {
    return this._bytesWritten === 0;
  }

  isBufferFull() {
    return this._bytesWritten === this.bufferSize;
  }

  /**
   * @param {Float32Array[][]} inputs
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  process(inputs) {
    // Grabbing the 1st channel similar to ScriptProcessorNode
    this.append(inputs[0][0]);

    return true;
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param {Float32Array} channelData
   */
  append(channelData) {
    if (this.isBufferFull()) {
      this.flush();
    }

    if (!channelData) return;

    for (let i = 0; i < channelData.length; i++) {
      this._buffer[this._bytesWritten++] = channelData[i];
    }
  }

  flush() {
    // trim the buffer if ended prematurely
    const buffer = this._bytesWritten < this.bufferSize ? this._buffer.slice(0, this._bytesWritten) : this._buffer;
    const result = this.downsampleBuffer(buffer, 44100, 16000);
    this.port.postMessage(result);
    this.initBuffer();
  }

  downsampleBuffer(buffer, sampleRate, outSampleRate) {
    if (outSampleRate == sampleRate) {
      return buffer;
    }
    if (outSampleRate > sampleRate) {
      throw new Error("downsampling rate show be smaller than original sample rate");
    }
    var sampleRateRatio = sampleRate / outSampleRate;
    var newLength = Math.round(buffer.length / sampleRateRatio);
    var result = new Int16Array(newLength);
    var offsetResult = 0;
    var offsetBuffer = 0;
    while (offsetResult < result.length) {
      var nextOffsetBuffer = Math.round((offsetResult + 1) * sampleRateRatio);
      var accum = 0,
        count = 0;
      for (var i = offsetBuffer; i < nextOffsetBuffer && i < buffer.length; i++) {
        accum += buffer[i];
        count++;
      }

      result[offsetResult] = Math.min(1, accum / count) * 0x7fff;
      offsetResult++;
      offsetBuffer = nextOffsetBuffer;
    }
    return result.buffer;
  }
}

registerProcessor("recorder.worklet", RecorderProcessor);
```

Install Socket.io-client on front end

```
npm i socket.io-client
```

**React component code**

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
import { default as React, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

const sampleRate = 16000;

const getMediaStream = () =>
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
      deviceId: "default",
      sampleRate: sampleRate,
      sampleSize: 16,
      channelCount: 1,
    },
    video: false,
  });

interface WordRecognized {
  final: boolean;
  text: string;
}

const AudioToText: React.FC = () => {
  const [connection, setConnection] = useState<io.Socket>();
  const [currentRecognition, setCurrentRecognition] = useState<string>();
  const [recognitionHistory, setRecognitionHistory] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [recorder, setRecorder] = useState<any>();
  const processorRef = useRef<any>();
  const audioContextRef = useRef<any>();
  const audioInputRef = useRef<any>();

  const speechRecognized = (data: WordRecognized) => {
    if (data.final) {
      setCurrentRecognition("...");
      setRecognitionHistory((old) => [data.text, ...old]);
    } else setCurrentRecognition(data.text + "...");
  };

  const connect = () => {
    connection?.disconnect();
    const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8081");
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("connected", socket.id);
      setConnection(socket);
    });

    socket.emit("send_message", "hello world");

    socket.emit("startGoogleCloudStream");

    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      console.log("received message", data);
    });

    socket.on("receive_audio_text", (data) => {
      speechRecognized(data);
      console.log("received audio text", data);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("disconnected", socket.id);
    });
  };

  const disconnect = () => {
    if (!connection) return;
    connection?.emit("endGoogleCloudStream");
    connection?.disconnect();
    processorRef.current?.disconnect();
    audioInputRef.current?.disconnect();
    audioContextRef.current?.close();
    setConnection(undefined);
    setRecorder(undefined);
    setIsRecording(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (connection) {
        if (isRecording) {
          return;
        }

        const stream = await getMediaStream();

        audioContextRef.current = new window.AudioContext();

        await audioContextRef.current.audioWorklet.addModule(
          "/src/worklets/recorderWorkletProcessor.js"
        );

        audioContextRef.current.resume();

        audioInputRef.current =
          audioContextRef.current.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

        processorRef.current = new AudioWorkletNode(
          audioContextRef.current,
          "recorder.worklet"
        );

        processorRef.current.connect(audioContextRef.current.destination);
        audioContextRef.current.resume();

        audioInputRef.current.connect(processorRef.current);

        processorRef.current.port.onmessage = (event: any) => {
          const audioData = event.data;
          connection.emit("send_audio_data", { audio: audioData });
        };
        setIsRecording(true);
      } else {
        console.error("No connection");
      }
    })();
    return () => {
      if (isRecording) {
        processorRef.current?.disconnect();
        audioInputRef.current?.disconnect();
        if (audioContextRef.current?.state !== "closed") {
          audioContextRef.current?.close();
        }
      }
    };
  }, [connection, isRecording, recorder]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container className="py-5 text-center">
        <Container fluid className="py-5 bg-primary text-light text-center ">
          <Container>
            <Button
              className={isRecording ? "btn-danger" : "btn-outline-light"}
              onClick={connect}
              disabled={isRecording}
            >
              Start
            </Button>
            <Button
              className="btn-outline-light"
              onClick={disconnect}
              disabled={!isRecording}
            >
              Stop
            </Button>
          </Container>
        </Container>
        <Container className="py-5 text-center">
          {recognitionHistory.map((tx, idx) => (
            <p key={idx}>{tx}</p>
          ))}
          <p>{currentRecognition}</p>
        </Container>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default AudioToText;
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const speech = require("@google-cloud/speech");

//use logger
const logger = require("morgan");

//use body parser
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

//use corrs
const cors = require("cors");

const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger("dev"));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

//TODO: run in terminal first to setup credentials export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./speech-to-text-key.json"

const speechClient = new speech.SpeechClient();

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  let recognizeStream = null;
  console.log("** a user connected - " + socket.id + " **\n");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("** user disconnected ** \n");
  });

  socket.on("send_message", (message) => {
    console.log("message: " + message);
    setTimeout(() => {
      io.emit("receive_message", "got this message" + message);
    }, 1000);
  });

  socket.on("startGoogleCloudStream", function (data) {
    startRecognitionStream(this, data);
  });

  socket.on("endGoogleCloudStream", function () {
    console.log("** ending google cloud stream **\n");
    stopRecognitionStream();
  });

  socket.on("send_audio_data", async (audioData) => {
    io.emit("receive_message", "Got audio data");
    if (recognizeStream !== null) {
      try {
        recognizeStream.write(audioData.audio);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error calling google api " + err);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("RecognizeStream is null");
    }
  });

  function startRecognitionStream(client) {
    console.log("* StartRecognitionStream\n");
    try {
      recognizeStream = speechClient
        .streamingRecognize(request)
        .on("error", console.error)
        .on("data", (data) => {
          const result = data.results[0];
          const isFinal = result.isFinal;

          const transcription = data.results
            .map((result) => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
            .join("\n");

          console.log(`Transcription: `, transcription);

          client.emit("receive_audio_text", {
            text: transcription,
            final: isFinal,
          });
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error streaming google api " + err);
    }
  }

  function stopRecognitionStream() {
    if (recognizeStream) {
      console.log("* StopRecognitionStream \n");
      recognizeStream.end();
    }
    recognizeStream = null;
  }
});

server.listen(8081, () => {
  console.log("WebSocket server listening on port 8081.");
});

// =========================== GOOGLE CLOUD SETTINGS ================================ //

// The encoding of the audio file, e.g. 'LINEAR16'
// The sample rate of the audio file in hertz, e.g. 16000
// The BCP-47 language code to use, e.g. 'en-US'
const encoding = "LINEAR16";
const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
const languageCode = "en-US"; //en-US
const alternativeLanguageCodes = ["en-US", "ko-KR"];

const request = {
  config: {
    encoding: encoding,
    sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
    languageCode: languageCode,
    //alternativeLanguageCodes: alternativeLanguageCodes,
    enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
    enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
    enableWordConfidence: true,
    enableSpeakerDiarization: true,
    diarizationSpeakerCount: 2,
    model: "video",
    //model: "command_and_search",
    useEnhanced: true,
    speechContexts: [
      {
        phrases: ["hello", "안녕하세요"],
      },
    ],
  },
  interimResults: true,
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing that answer above, that's incredibly helpful. Haven't seen this particular niche well documented anywhere else.

Comment: You are welcome @AlexandrKurilin. I'm glad this helped. Please reach out anytime.

Comment: thank you - for what reason do we need to replace `ScriptProcessorNode`? I found this info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_AudioWorklet

Comment: @user3325025, could you please make your question a bit more clear? In this code, we used the Web Audio API's processor worklet node to process the stream into chunks and then send them to the backend in realtime.

Comment: my assumption is you used the worklet node (and not the `ScriptProcessorNode`) because of the statement in the link that I found while trying to understand your solution: "The drawback to ScriptProcessorNode was that it ran on the main thread, thus blocking everything else going on until it completed execution. This was far less than ideal, especially for something that can be as computationally expensive as audio processing."?

Comment: This code uses the [web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_AudioWorklet) and not the `ScriptProcessorNode`. If you look inside the react code, we created an audio-context that has an audio-worklet that runs off the main thread. We then gave it code to run using the `audioWorklet.addModule()` function. So in conclusion, the audio processing task does not actually run on the main thread.