How to get better transcription accuracy from Google speech to text API when streaming microphone audio from a web browser?
I'm trying to make a Vue component that does real-time speech-to-text transcription. The audio recorded should be limited to around 5 seconds.
I found this implementation that uses the Audio worklet to down sample the audio before sending it to the backend for transcription.
However, when I tried using it I get very low transcription accuracy from Google Speech API. It's usually 0... Here is the component code:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';

const transcription = ref('');
const isRecording = ref(false);

const socket = ref<Socket | null>(null);
const audioContext = ref<AudioContext | null>(null);
const audioInput = ref<MediaStreamAudioSourceNode | null>(null);
const audioWorkletNode = ref<AudioWorkletNode | null>(null);

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  socket.value?.disconnect();
});

const startRecording = async () => {
  socket.value = io('http://localhost:3000', { 
    query: {
      lang: 'en-US',
    } 
  });

  socket.value.on('transcription', (data: string) => {
    transcription.value = data;
  });

  if (!isRecording.value) {
    isRecording.value = true;

    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ 
        video: false,
        audio: {
          channelCount: 1,
          sampleSize: 16,
          noiseSuppression: true,
          sampleRate: 16000,
        }
      });

      audioContext.value = new window.AudioContext();
      // load module in a JS file and add it to the current worklet
      // source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74822616/9884424
      await audioContext.value.audioWorklet.addModule(
        new URL('../assets/RecorderProcessor.js', import.meta.url).toString()
      );
      audioContext.value.resume();
      audioInput.value = audioContext.value.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      audioWorkletNode.value = new AudioWorkletNode(
        audioContext.value,
        "audio-recorder-worklet"
      );
      audioWorkletNode.value.connect(audioContext.value.destination);
      audioContext.value.resume();
      audioInput.value.connect(audioWorkletNode.value);
      audioWorkletNode.value.port.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data.byteLength > 0 && socket) {
          socket.value?.emit('audio-stream', { audio: event.data }); 
        }
      };

      setTimeout(() => {
        stopRecording();
      }, 5000);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error accessing the microphone:', error);
      isRecording.value = false;
    }
  }
};

const stopRecording = async () => {
  audioInput.value?.disconnect();
  audioWorkletNode.value?.disconnect();
  audioContext.value?.close();

  audioInput.value?.mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
    track.stop();
  });

  audioContext.value = null;
  audioInput.value = null;
  audioWorkletNode.value = null;

  isRecording.value = false;
  socket.value?.disconnect();
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Real-Time Transcription</h1>
    <button @click="startRecording" :disabled="isRecording">
      {{ isRecording ? 'Recording...' : 'Start Recording' }}
    </button>
    <p>Transcription: {{ transcription }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

And here is the relevant backend code:
  createRecognitionStream = (languageCode?: string) => {
    const request = {
      config: {
        encoding: encoding,
        languageCode: languageCode || 'en-US',
        sampleRateHertz: 16000,
        audioChannelCount: 2,
      },
      interimResults: true,
  };

    return client
      .streamingRecognize(request)
      .on('error', (err) => {
        logger.error('Error during speech recognition:', err);
      });
  };

  const io = new Server(server);
  
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {    
    const languageCode = socket.handshake.query.languageCode as string;
    const recognitionStream = createRecognitionStream(languageCode);
  
    socket.on("audio-stream", async (audioData) => {
      recognitionStream.write(audioData.audio);
    });

    recognitionStream.on("data", (data) => {
      const transcription = data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;

      if (transcription) {
        socket.emit("transcription", transcription);
      }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      recognitionStream.destroy();
    });
  });

What could cause this low transcription accuracy? Do I need to do some additional processing before sending the audio stream to the backend like changing the encoding or down sampling (adding the down sampling in the worklet from the other question does not seem to improve the accuracy)?
